# Making a racing game in javascript. When trying to simulate oncoming cars, I am not able to create more cars when the other cars have reached the end

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am trying to make a racing game where the user must try to avoid the oncoming cars. To create the oncoming cars, I have created a class called obstacles. In addition, I have a function that draws the obstacles and in that function, I have an if statement that checks whether the cars have reached close to the bottom of the canvas so that I can create the next 3 obstacles(Cars). However, the program seems to be inconsistent with creating the new cars and sometimes doesn't even work at all. How should I fix this? Thank you in Advance. Here is my code so far:

```
<body>
    <p><span id="val">here</span></p>
    <canvas width="400" height="500" id="myCanvas"></canvas>
    <script>
        "use strict"
        var a=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var c=a.getContext("2d");
        
        var obs=[];
        
        function randomNumber(){
            var rand=(Math.random()*400)+1;
            if(rand<400/3){return 50}
            else if(rand>400/3&&rand<400*2/3){return 180}
            else if(rand>rand<400*2/3){return 300}
        }
        
        class obstacles{
            constructor(x){
                this.x=x;
                this.y=-(Math.floor(Math.random()*300)+1);
            }
            
            show(){
                c.fillStyle="blue";
                c.beginPath();
                c.rect(this.x,this.y,40,70);
                c.fill();
                c.closePath();
            }
            
            move(){
                this.y+=3;
            }
        }
        createObstacles();
        function createObstacles(){
            var x;
            for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
                x=randomNumber();
                obs[i]=new obstacles(x);
            }
        }
        
        function draw(){
            c.clearRect(0,0,400,500);
            var x;
            for(var j=0;j<obs.length;j++){
                x=randomNumber();
                obs[j].show();
                obs[j].move();
            }
            for(var i=0;i<obs.length;i++){
                if(obs[i].y==350){
                    obs.push(new obstacles(x))
                }
            }
        }
        window.setInterval(draw,17);
        
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create an obstacle, it is given a random y position. Then, whenever it moves, its y changes by 3 in your move function. However, when you go to check if it has reached the bottom, you only check if the y is exactly 350: `obs[i].y==350`. It is completely possible that, given where the obstacle started, on one of its moves it moved 3 spaces and completely skipped 350! In this case your code would never trigger.

An easy solution to this is simply to change your `==` to a `>` so that it checks if the y ever exceeds 350, not just when it is exactly equal to it:

```
for(var i=0;i<obs.length;i++){
                if(obs[i].y>350){
                    obs.push(new obstacles(x))
                }
            }
```

Hopefully this solves your problem. I haven't actually test-run your code though, so there might be other bugs. Good luck with your project!